# Dudas sobre conexión en Hosting

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema para conectar mi aplicación que ya esta alojada en el hosting que tengo contratado, estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, en Php Admin configure mi base de datos como epalacio_cobranzas tengo el usuario de base de datos epalacio_root con la contraseña recontra confirmada que es "X1234@1978" ahora cuando trato de ingresar por el login al momento de establecer la conexión a la base de datos me arroja el siguiente error:

**"Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'epalacio_root'@'localhost' to database 'epalacio_cobranzas'' in /home/epalacio/public_html/libs/SPDO.php:10"**

Entiendo que por algún motivo me esta denegando el acceso el problema es que llamo a mi hosting y las personas no saben nada del asunto y se excusan diciéndome que ellos no arreglan problemas de programación.
como podran notar estoy trabajado con PDO y mi archivo config con los parametros de conexion es este:

```
$config->set('dbhost', 'localhost');
$config->set('dbname', 'epalacio_cobranzas');
$config->set('dbuser', 'epalacio_root');
$config->set('dbpass', 'X1234@1978');
```

Demas esta recalcar que de manera local obviamente con otros parametros de conexión mi aplicación funciona perfectamente. estoy desesperado ya voy 2 dias en esto. cualquier ayuda me sirve. muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que son las credenciales de conexión correcta? Por favor muestra el código de conexión que usas... y no dejes los datos reales, no sea que te hackeen tu sistema.

Comment: La verdad estoy 100% seguro del nombre de la Base de datos (epalacio_cobranzas)  ,  el nombre (epalacios_root) y contraseña (X1234@1978) del usuario de la base de datos(todos estos datos estan verificados desde el PHPADMIN del CPANEL del hosting). lo que no estoy seguro del nombre del servidor asumo que es localhost por que este debe trabajar de manera local es lo unico que no estoy 100% seguro. la contraseña que puse aqui por motivos de seguridad es falsa pero esta verificada 100% asi que no puede ser la contraseña.

Comment: El nombre del host debe aparecer en la página de ayuda de tu hosting, si es que se trata de un hosting algo decente. En algunos casos usan también `127.0.0.1` que sería prácticamente lo mismo que `localhost` y en algunos el nombre de usuario y de la bd va precedido del nombre de usuario de cPanel, algo así: `usuariocpanel_usuariobd`.

Comment: No asumas que localhost es tu servidor para base de datos, porque con casi total seguridad no lo es. Debes mirar en la compañía que te proporciona la base de datos (¿la misma que te proporciona el hosting web?) y mirar la configuración de la base de datos.

Comment: El error que esta saliendo es directamente a sobre los permisos o credenciales que tienes. Comunmente(que a mi parecer este es el caso) pueda que la bd no este en el mismo servidor que el hosting, intenta acceder a tu base de datos con unicamente los parametros que tienes ahí, desde tu Computador. Revisa con mas seguridad las propiedades de tu bd, y si puedes, intenta la misma conexión con pdo desde otro equipo (descarta que el error no sea tuyo) Saludos!!! y no dudes en volver a preguntar

Comment: Era los privilegios del usuario de la base de Datos, el usuario estaba creado pero no tenia ningun privilegio. gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Bien, siempre hay algo que se nos escapa :(, Saludos!!